# Why a NULL value in PostgreSQL table is returned as 0?

Tags: postgresql, qt

I have the following PostgreSQL table, called *mytable*:

```
 id |     col1 |    col2 
----+----------+--------
  0 |          |       0
  1 |        0 |       1
  2 |        0 |       2
```

I am trying to get the value of `col1`, where `col2` is equal to `0`:

```
const QString &str("SELECT col1 FROM mytable WHERE col2 = 0");

query.exec(str);

if (!query.next()) {
    qDebug() << query.value(0).type();                
}
```

The problem is, that I am expecting a `NULL`, because of the missing value, but instead `0` is returned. The type of *QVariant* is `int`.

Why is it like that and could it be fixed?

Comment: What do you get if instead of `if (!query...` you write `while (query.next()) {
  qDebug() << query.record().field("col1").value().isNull();
 };`?